# Why is my text not centered in HTML table?

Tags: html, html-table, text-align

I want to create a simple login form. I almost have it done but the text in my table doesn't go to the right. I am using `<span>` for this. My HTML code is here.

```
<div id="login-container">
<form action="login.php" method="post" >
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><span>Username:</span></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><span>Password</span></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" ></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="off">remember me?</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="button"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my CSS is here. When I use `float:right` then it goes to the right.

```
span {
    color:black;
    font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean text doesn't go to the right?

Comment: Instead of giving text align to span give it to td, hopefully you need to create class for td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`text-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html) property does not apply to inline elements, and `span` elements are inline by default. A minimal fix is to add

```
span { display: block }
```

However, such rules are risky; you should probably use a more restrictive selector, but this depends on the page structure.

Instead of `span`, `label` should be used for accessibility; but ths does not change the basic issue, since `label` is inline, too.

Alternatively, set the style on the `td` elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` property doesn't apply to inline elements and `span` is an inline element. Therefore, the `text-align` property doesn't apply to it.

If you don't want to use `float:right;`

You could use:

```
td{
    text-align:right;
}
```

**P.S:** It would be smarter to give that particular `td` an *ID*, Otherwise all `td` will be aligned to the right like you see in the demo below.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jarvoey7/)**

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` takes up only the  width of the text available, so assigning `text-align:right` to `span` wont make any difference, you should apply it to the `td`.

**EXAMPLE**:
See this link for better understanding about [**Span**](http://coursesweb.net/html/div-span)

**CSS**:

```
span {
color:black;
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:13px;

}
td{text-align:right;}
```

See this fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ucy37gL/)

P.S: your question is not clear, your heading says "it won't go center" but your explanation says "it won't go right". Assuming you want it to go right i have given the solution.